# How to mock the internally created objects by class API?

Tags: java, mockito

The piece of code I want to write Junit tests for :

```
class my_service {
  public void init() {
    Class_A a = new Class_A();
    Class_B b = new Class_B();
    if(a.isPresent()) {
      dosomething();
    }
    if(b.isPresent()) {
      dosomethingelse();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to mock Class_A & Class_B & their methods. Is their a way where I can inject mock objects of Class_A & Class_B ?

Comment: As you are initiating class A and class B in the method, you will not be able to inject them. An alternative approach is to pass them into the method as parameters, then you can mock them and pass them into the method for the test

Answer (score 0):

Have a constructor that takes instances of `Class_A` and `Class_B` and set them as instance/field variables in `my_service` and then `init()` can use those variables. In your test you can then pass in mocks via e.g. Mockito. This apporach can then be used with a dependency injection framework to inject Class_A and Class_B at runtime such as Spring.

Also Java class name best practise is to separate different words with captials so `ClassA` `MyService` and not contain underscores

Answer (score 0):

I would use arguments to create the instances of ClassB and ClassA (using conventional camel-casing):

```
class MyService {

  public void init(ClassA a, ClassB b) {

    if(a.isPresent()) {
       dosomething();
    }

    if(b.isPresent()) {
    dosomethingelse();
    }

  }

}
```

Then you can mock the objects in your test to be passed in:

```
   ClassA a = Mockito.mock(ClassA.class);
   ClassB b = Mockito.mock(ClassB.class);
   
//add in logic for action of a and b when doSomething() is called
  
  myService.init(a, b);
```